# i want to clear or block input click old datas when i click or focus in the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here my codes;

```
<input type="text" name="yuz" id="yuz" /> 

                     $("#yuz").keyup(function() {
    var dInput = $(this).val();
  var sum=100;
  var toplam=parseInt(sum)*parseInt(dInput);

        $("#yuz1").val(isNaN(toplam) ? "0" : toplam.toFixed(2)); 
});
```

when i click in the input, the old datas coming .. but i don't wanna see old datas...i tried default value but when i click in the input the data is hiding.. how i can block old datas to come? thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean autocomplete attribute?

```
<input autocomplete="off />
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7egbwqd/)

It's hard to know what exactly is wrong but given the code, if you have input with id yuz1 the code should work. But if yuz1 is for example div, you should use:

```
$("#yuz1").text(isNaN(toplam) ? "0" : toplam.toFixed(2));
```

Hopefully this solves your problem!